# Ruby 'require' with wildcard expression

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to load files that only match a specific string? For example, suppose I want to load files that matches `account1.rb` `account2.rb` and so on. I want to be able to do something like

```
require File.expand_path("../account*.rb", __FILE__)
```

but of course this does not work. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the same thing with a loop:

```
Dir.glob(File.expand_path("../account*.rb", __FILE__)).each do |file|
  require file
end
```

The `expand_path` method only resolves paths. It does not expand wildcards.

Comment: what if I want to match a specific character? "account_a.rb", "account_b.rb" and so on

Comment: A single character is represented by `?`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use this to create a test-suite for Minitest without using Rspec. The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

Dir.glob("*_test.rb").each do |file|
    require_relative file
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
Dir.entries( File.dirname( __FILE__ ) ).

    grep( /test.*\.rb/ ) { | file | require_relative file }
```

Unfortunately Ruby doesn't allow newlines before the dot, so the ideal form doesn't work:

```
Dir.entries( File.dirname( __FILE__ ) )

    .grep( /test.*\.rb/ ) { | file | require_relative file }
```